# Notation related to the Borel hierarchy

Tags: measure-theory, notation, descriptive-set-theory

I'm reading an article where the author uses many classes in the Borel hierarchy: namely, $\mathcal F_\sigma$, $G_\delta$, $\mathcal F_{\sigma\delta}$, etc. In this context, he mentions the class $\mathcal F\cap\mathcal G$ (no subscripts). Does anyone knows what this notation means?

Comment: Can you give a reference to the article?

Comment: http://journals.impan.pl/cgi-bin/doi?sm208-1-5. Theorem 4.5

Comment: My sincerest efforts couldn't get the site to agree to my paywall... I'll swing by the office tomorrow and try again from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pointclass $\mathcal{F\cap G}$ usually denotes the collection of clopen sets, at least in Hausdorff's convention going back to his *Grundzüge der Mengenlehre* (1914). Hausdorff [defined topological spaces in terms of neighborhood bases](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/70445/) and he wrote

$$\mathcal{F} = \{F \subseteq X \mid F \text{ is closed}\},\quad
\mathcal{G} = \{G \subseteq X \mid G \text{ is open}\}$$

for the corresponding collections of closed sets and open sets.
Here $F$ is for French *fermé* (closed) and $G$ is for German *Gebiet* ((open) neighborhood). Thus, $$\mathcal{F \cap G} = \{H \subseteq X \mid H \text{ is closed and open}\}.$$

---

For every collection $\mathcal{H} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ Hausdorff defined
$$
\mathcal{H}_\sigma = \left\{A \subseteq X \mid \exists H_n \in \mathcal{H}, n \in \mathbb{N} : A = \bigcup\nolimits_{n\in \mathbb{N}} H_n\right\}
$$
and 
$$
\mathcal{H}_\delta = \left\{A \subseteq X \mid \exists H_n \in \mathcal{H}, n \in \mathbb{N} : A = \bigcap\nolimits_{n\in \mathbb{N}} H_n\right\}.
$$
Here $\sigma$ is the small Greek *s* for German *Summe* (sum, old term/notation for union) and $\delta$ is the small Greek *d* for German *Durchschnitt* (intersection). If I remember correctly, he also used $\mathcal{H}_s$ and $\mathcal{H}_d$ for finite unions and intersections from $\mathcal{H}$ which partly explains the usage of Greek letters.

Applying this to the classes $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{F,G,F_\sigma,G_\delta}, \dots$, you recover the usual pointclasses in the Borel hierarchy.