# Closed and Open Set - History of Terms

Tags: general-topology, terminology, math-history

I know very little in the way of math history, but I question that was bothering me recently is where the terms open and closed came from in topology. I know that it's easy to ascribe a sense of openness/closedness to said sets, but I feel like there are a lot of other, more appropriate words that could have been used. On a related note, I was wondering who first developed the idea of open/closed sets, and who first used those words to describe them.

Comment: related threads: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70445/origins-of-the-modern-definition-of-topology) [2](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19152/why-is-a-topology-made-up-of-open-sets).

Comment: For future reference; similar question I asked few months back: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6430/basic-theorems-in-topology-who-proved-them-first

Answer (score 2):

This answer addresses your question on who first actually used the words "open" and "closed" to describe open and closed sets.  It seems, according to [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0315086008000050), like the first mention of this language was in René Baire's doctoral dissertation,

> Sur les fonctions de variables réelles
>   Annali di matematica pura ed applicata (3), 3 (1899), pp. 1–123

which I believe first appears in page 7 of the [document](https://archive.org/stream/surlesfonctions00bairgoog#page/n152/mode/2up) in the context of defining an "open domain."  The term itself was first actually defined by Lebesgue in his dissertation, *Intégrale, longueur, aire*, (which I cannot find an online copy of) for the purpose of setting up Lebesgue measure.

I think the rest of your question should be addressed to your satisfaction between the linked article and related MSE/MO threads.

Answer (score 0):

the followings archives corresponds to the doctoral thesis of Henri Lebesgue:

You can search for Analysis situs, old name for the actual topology.Lebesgue and Rham (french mathematicians) wrote about  that subject.

sincerely

Hugo Mancera
Colombia